# С# Нужен алгоритм для отрисовки изображений с разным соотношением сторон в одном "квадрате"

Tags: c#, изображения, graphics

Что-то подобное можно увидеть телеграмме или в других мессенджерах.
[image: Пример 1]
[image: Пример 2]
[image: Пример 3]

Обратите внимание, как работает алгоритм из примера, при разном количестве картинок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Из ваших картинок, я не вижу зависимости между числами и расположением (координатами x y, да между ширина:высота отношение есть, но не понятно почему 1:1 больше чем 4:3 в одном случае и меньше в другом). Для начала правильно составьте правила размещения квадратов - из правил уже можно будет выписать алгоритм.

Comment: Это лишь пример, показывающий как это реализовано в telegram. Ваша реализация может использовать любой принцип.

Comment: Из моих наблюдений, telegram берёт первое изображение за основу. Потом, если его ширина больше высоты, то остальные изображения рисуются под ним, при этом общая ширина всех остальных изображений не должна превышать ширину первого. Аналитично, если высота больше ширины, только теперь остальные фотографии рисуются справа, а не снизу.

Comment: [Задача раскроя](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Задача_раскроя) - обрадую: это NP-полная задача...